# ios7 and ios8 landscape modes - part of the screen doesn't response

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, uikit

I'm developing an application in iOS8 in landscape mode and everything works fine. I'm using UIKit and don't support portrait mode at all.

Im trying to customise it to iOS7 but the frame that I'm getting is always like the iPhone is in a portrait mode.

I know that the in iOS8 there was a major change with the width and height and it's different in iOS7.

I have the following method which I used to set the window n the appDelegate and when I need the frame at the ViewControllers.

I'm doing the following:

```
- (CGRect) screenRect {
    CGRect screenRect = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    if ((NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
    return CGRectMake(0,0,screenRect.size.height, screenRect.size.width);
}
return screenRect;
```

}

The views look fine but the left/right side of the screen (depends on the device orientation) behaves like it's outside the frame. i.e doesn't response to gestures!
When I'm setting the fame to the new "screenRect" it keeps turning back to the device bounds.

Thank you very much.